# cs50 week4 filter(less comfortable) blur and sepia function

Tags: c, image, cs50

```
#include "helpers.h"
#include "math.h"

// Convert image to grayscale
void grayscale(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round((image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j].rgbtRed) / 3.0);
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
        }
    }
    return;
}

// Convert image to sepia
void sepia(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            //get values according to the given equasion.//

            int sepiaRed = round(.393 * image[i][j].rgbtRed + .769 * image[i][j].rgbtGreen + .189 * image[i][j].rgbtBlue);
            int sepiaGreen = round(.349 * image[i][j].rgbtRed + .686 * image[i][j].rgbtGreen + .168 * image[i][j].rgbtBlue);
            int sepiaBlue = round(.272 * image[i][j].rgbtRed + .534 * image[i][j].rgbtGreen + .131 * image[i][j].rgbtBlue);
            // update value for each color, the if checks if it exceeds 255 to cap the value to 255. //
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = sepiaGreen;
            if (image[i][j].rgbtGreen > 255)
            {
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = 255;
            }

            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = sepiaBlue;
            if (image[i][j].rgbtBlue > 255)
            {
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = 255;
            }

            image[i][j].rgbtRed = sepiaRed;
            if (image[i][j].rgbtRed > 255)
            {
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = 255;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}

// Reflect image horizontally
void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < (width / 2); j++)
        {
            RGBTRIPLE temp = image[i][j];
            image[i][j] = image[i][width - j - 1];
            image[i][width - j - 1] = temp;
        }
    }
    return;
}

// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];
    int blue = 0;
    int red = 0;
    int green = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            copy[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
     }
     for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
     {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            blue = 0;
            red = 0;
            green = 0;
            counter = 0;
            for (int s = i - 1; s < i + 2; s++)
            {
                for (int m = j - 1; m < j + 2; m++)
                {
                    //this condition will make sure if a grid is not in the loop it will not be included(handeling edgee case).//
                    if (s < 0 || m < 0 || s > height - 1 || m > width - 1)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        blue += copy[s][m].rgbtBlue;
                        green += copy[s][m].rgbtGreen;
                        red += copy[s][m].rgbtRed;
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
            }
            image [i][j].rgbtBlue = round(blue / counter);
            image [i][j].rgbtGreen = round(green / counter);
            image [i][j].rgbtRed = round(red / counter);
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

I can't pass the test for function blur in the middle pixel. corners and edges I passed it. In the sepia function I cant seem to pass the more complex 3*3 image and 4*4 image (I passed the simple 3*3). What could be the problem?
In one test the difference in values is as small as 1 but others it is like 100.

Comment: Questions asking for debugging help without any evidence of effort on the part of the programmer are liable to be closed rather quickly. Last time I looked, the CS50 development environment included an excellent debugger. Now would be a good time to learn how to use it.

Comment: `round(blue / counter)` won't round it, because it was already truncated by the integer division. Try `round((double)blue / counter)`

Comment: `if (image[i][j].rgbtGreen > 255)` This won't work. The fields in that struct can only hold 8 bits, i.e. values up to 255. If you add up values to a larger value that will already be chopped when you assign it back to that field. You must use another variable with a larger range for doing the math and only then check for range.

Comment: If you have the test data of the failing test, your first step should be to feed that data into your function and step through each instruction in a debugger. Then you can inspect the variables' contents with their expected values. And of course you should also provide these test cases to use within your question. Don't just describe that "some test if only off by 1..." Show us: What test, what value, what expected value?

Comment: Please also describe which function produces values off-by-1 and which produces results way off. My guess: Wrong rounding is the reason for that off-by-one issue. Overrun of range can cause tha case with larger error. But we don't have magic chrystal balls and generally don't like wild guessing.

Comment: Note: SO only works if you respond to feedback

Comment: When I solved this problem, I forgot that in C you should divide not by e.g. 4, but 4.0 - it brought so much pain to find out what the hell was wrong with my code...

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems:

In the sepia test, you check if the computed component exceeds `255` after storing it to the RGBTRIPLE member. This does not work because the members have type `BYTE` which cannot only hold values from `0` to `255` so any values beyond this range will have been reduced modulo 256 already.

Here is a modified version:

```
// Convert image to sepia
void sepia(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            // get values according to the given equation. //
            int sepiaRed   = round(.393 * image[i][j].rgbtRed + .769 * image[i][j].rgbtGreen + .189 * image[i][j].rgbtBlue);
            int sepiaGreen = round(.349 * image[i][j].rgbtRed + .686 * image[i][j].rgbtGreen + .168 * image[i][j].rgbtBlue);
            int sepiaBlue  = round(.272 * image[i][j].rgbtRed + .534 * image[i][j].rgbtGreen + .131 * image[i][j].rgbtBlue);

            // cap the component values to 255. //
            if (sepiaRed   > 255)
                sepiaRed   = 255;
            if (sepiaGreen > 255)
                sepiaGreen = 255;
            if (sepiaBlue  > 255)
                sepiaBlue  = 255;

            // update the pixel values //
            image[i][j].rgbtRed   = sepiaRed;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = sepiaGreen;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue  = sepiaBlue;
        }
    }
}
```

For the `blur` function, the way you average the component values is incorrect: you use integer arithmetics in `red / counter` so `round` does not actually do anything. You should either implement rounding using integer arithmetics or use floating point arithmetics in the computation for example by defining `counter` as a `double`.

Here is a modified version:

```
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width]) {
    RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            copy[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
     }
     for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            int blue  = 0;
            int red   = 0;
            int green = 0;
            double counter = 0;
            for (int s = i - 1; s < i + 2; s++) {
                // check for top and bottom edge //
                if (s < 0 || s >= height)
                    continue;
                for (int m = j - 1; m < j + 2; m++) {
                    // check for left and right edge //
                    if (m < 0 || m >= width)
                        continue;
                    red   += copy[s][m].rgbtRed;
                    green += copy[s][m].rgbtGreen;
                    blue  += copy[s][m].rgbtBlue;
                    counter += 1;
                }
            }
            image[i][j].rgbtRed   = round(red   / counter);
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(green / counter);
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue  = round(blue  / counter);
        }
    }
}
```